# Стрелки в контейнере slick slider?

Tags: html, css, slick.js

Как можно поместить такие стрелки в подобный контейнер, чтобы было под заголовком. Знаю, что можно спозиционировать каждую стрелку, но мне кажется что лучше в обертке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в чём сейчас проблема? Кнопки можно поместить в один `div`, а для каждой стрелки-дива, которые будут в нём находиться, сделать фиксированную ширину и, например, `display: inline-block`

Comment: добавьте в вопрос ваш [mcve]

Comment: Почитайте внимательно документацию для slick, там есть возможность повестить функционал стрелок на любой кастомный блок где-бы он не находился

Answer (score 1, accepted):

размещаете обертку в нужном месте, а при подключении слайдера в js
добавляете следующую строку в настройках слайдера:

```
appendArrows: '.название класса обертки',
```

можно привязать кнопки "prev" и "next" также разместив их в html разметке и прописав в настройке слайдера следующие строки:

```
prevArrow: '.класс для стрелки перехода на предыдущий слайд',
nextArrow: '.класс для стрелки перехода на следующий слайд'
```